# Matching all strings of the format Names#Age#Gender#City

Tags: php, regex

I have a number of strings some in the format `Names#`,or `Names#Age` or `Names#Age#Gender` or `Names#Age#Gender#City`

I want to match only the strings that satisfy this format `Names#Age#Gender#City`.

The regex i want shall be used in this query for a cron job i am running

`SELECT text_message from incoming_sms where text_message REGEXP '^\w+(?:$\w+)+$`

My regex `^\w+(?:$\w+)+$` does not seem to work.

How can i fix my regex to match `Names#Age#Gender#City` exactly?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^([^#\n]+#){3}[^\n#]+$
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dZ1vT6/60